# Module not found: Can't resolve '*.module.scss'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm new in react. when I'm enter a code using Grid component in material-ui.com it shows this error. *Module not found: Can't resolve '*.module.scss'*  Do anyone know how to solve this.?

here is my code,

```
import { Grid, makeStyles, Paper } from '@material-ui/core';
import React from 'react';
import MC_MainH1 from '../components/MC_MainH1';
import MC_Para from '../components/MC_Para';
import image from './../img/4636927.jpg';
import './../components/styles/Para.css';
import classes from '*.module.scss';

function Features() {
    
    return (
        <Grid container>
        <center>                            
            <Grid item xs={5}>
                <MC_MainH1 mainH1="Features"/>                    
            </Grid>            
        </center> 
            <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Grid item xs={6}>
                    <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6</Paper>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>           
        </Grid>    
    )
}

export default Features
```

Comment: What is this *.module.scss?

Comment: What package manager are you using? if you're using webpack you need to install the sass-loader. Also, have you installed sass? `npm install --save-dev sass` for sass and `npm install --save-dev sass-loader` for the sass loader if you're package manager doesn't already handle it for you

Comment: Is the "classes" coming from `const classes = useStyles();` but you forgot to include it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you actually need to import classes. I had the same issue. Turns out the auto-complete simply added the import statement when I typed in classes.

To style material UI components,

`

```
 const useStyles = makeStyles((theme)=>{
  //Styling required
 });

 const classes = useStyles();
```

`